# How add html and scripts on wordpress plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

I'm thinking of creating a simple plugin for my website.
I want to add the video js script here

```
 <?php
    /**
    Plugin Name: name
    Plugin URI: url
    Description: desc 
    Version: 1.1.1
    Author: auth
    Author URI: rul
    Text Domain: sulg
    */
```

this is the html that what i want to include on my WordPress Plugin

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <link rel="icon" href="/assets/icons/logo16.png">
        <link href="/assets/videojs/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/assets/videojs/videojs-download-button.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/assets/videojs/videojs-resolution-switcher.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="/assets/videojs/video.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/videojs/videojs-download-button.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/videojs/videojs-resolution-switcher.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/videojs/videojs.hotkeys.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/videojs/videojs-components.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/js/ResizeSensor.js"></script>

        <script src="/assets/js/onevideo.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/js/oneVideoPlayer.js"></script>
        <script src="VidPlaySite.js"></script>
        <style>
            .reloadButton {
                display: block !important;
                z-index: 10000 !important;
                background-image: url('/assets/icons/reloadNormal.png') !important;
            }
            .reloadButton:hover {
                background-image: url('/assets/icons/reloadHover.png') !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="overflow: hidden;background:#000000;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;">
        <video id="oneVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto"> 
            <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
        </video>
        <input type="file" id="srtSelector" accept=".vtt, .srt, .txt" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;width:0;height:0;">

    </body>
</html>
```

so i want to include the player video.js script, it is very difficult for me,therefore I asked for help. Thanks

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To register your script you can use `wp_enqueue_script()` function. `wp_enqueue_script()` function takes 5 parameters.

- `$handle`(string) (Required) : Name of the script. Should be unique.
- `$src` (string) (Optional): Full URL of the script, or path of the script relative to the WordPress root directory.

  Default value: ''
- `$deps` (array) (Optional): An array of registered script handles this script depends on.

  Default value: array()
- `$ver` (string|bool|null) (Optional): String specifying script version number, if it has one, which is added to the URL as a query string for cache busting purposes. If version is set to false, a version number is automatically added equal to current installed WordPress version. If set to null, no version is added.

  Default value: false
- `$in_footer` (bool) (Optional): Whether to enqueue the script before `</body>` instead of in the `<head>`.
  Default 'false'.

  Default value: false

Example:

```
function video_plugin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/video.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'video_plugin_scripts' );
```

For more details on plugin development you can follow [Introduction to Plugin Development](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro/) on wordpress documentation.